# Why is the SQL OLE DB Driver for SQL Server truncating seconds and fractional seconds for datetime values?

Tags: .net, sql-server, oledb

We're introducing the OLE DB Driver for SQL Server (MSOLEDBSQL) in our legacy .NET application to support TLS 1.2. The application uses ADO.NET and has thus far been using the obsolete OLE DB Provider for SQL Server (SQLOLEDB) to connect to SQL Server instances.

In short, with the new provider, a datetime object with a value representing

```
'2019-04-10 12:10:55.340'
```

will be truncated and then saved as

```
'2019-04-10 12:10:00.000'
```

Currently, the only modifications are in the connection string, where we now for MSOLEDBSQL have `DataTypeCompatibility=80` to have the driver correctly map the new data types to the ADO data types. All existing OLE DB parameters for datetime fields only define the size but not scale.

This combination might seem to be a feasible part of the reason for the truncation. At least if one reads the changed behaviors when going from SQL Native Client 9.x to MSOLEDBSQL (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/applications/updating-an-application-from-sql-server-2005-native-client?view=sql-server-2017).

> An application built with OLE DB Driver for SQL Server that connects to a SQL Server 2005 server will truncate seconds and fractional seconds for time portion of data sent to the server if you bind to a datetime column with a type identifier of DBTYPE_DBTIMESTAMP (OLE DB) or SQL_TIMESTAMP (ODBC) and a scale of 0.
>
> For example:
>
> Input data: 1994-08-21 21:21:36.000
>
> Inserted data: 1994-08-21 21:21:00.000

**If the above combination is the culprit to the truncation then how can you specify a scale that is > 0 without getting an OleDBException with the following message?**

> 'The fractional part of the provided time value overflows the scale of the corresponding SQL Server parameter or column. Increase bScale in DBPARAMBINDINFO or column scale to correct this error.'

**Additionally, is it somehow possible to set a default scale to be used for all OLE DB parameters of type DBTimeStamp?**

Comment: Are the "C#" and ".NET" tags correct? Typically .NET applications use ADO.NET and the native implementation of SQL connectivity (`SqlConnection` et al.). Using old-school COM-based ADO from .NET is technically possible, but it would be highly unusual. It matters because I suspect the problem may actually be ADO (or rather, how it's being used by the client technology).

Comment: @JeroenMostert, using ADO classic in .NET is often due to taking shortcuts when migrating a legacy VB6 application or cloning such code. It seems 15-years of accrued interest on that tech debt is coming due.

Comment: Updated the question with some details clarifying that the application in question is a .NET application using ADO.NET. The "C#" tag was removed as it was too broad or irrelevant.

Comment: What version of the .NET Framework (so the runtime, not the version your app was compiled for)? If you're using OLE DB from ADO.NET it's not clear why you would need to use `DataTypeCompatibility=80` -- even really old versions support SQL 2005+ and should not need this setting (which is intended to give SQL Server 2000 semantics). What goes wrong without it?

Comment: Oh, and just for completeness and because I shouldn't assume things -- does your application have the option to use any connection string and any ADO.NET provider? If it does, consider not using OLE DB at all but the native SQL provider, as it does not suffer from these discrepancies. The only reason you might not be able to is if you can't upgrade your .NET Framework to a version where `SqlConnection` supports TLS 1.2 (4.5+), but this is worth considering far more than trying to get OLE DB to play nice. (Your application may need config changes, but should not need recompilation.)

Comment: The runtime version is 4.0. I suspect that all the reading made me blind to the fact that `DataTypeCompatibility=80` only seems to be necessary for **ADO** applications. Leaving it out of the connection string (or having it set to 0) then further requires the scale to be explicitly set for each and every one of the OleDbParameters whose type is DbTimeStamp.

Comment: We need to support both SQL Server and Oracle. As such, the application has during the years been developed to now heavily rely on OLE DB.

Comment: AFAICT from the source, the `OleDb*` classes have no interesting logic for the scale at all, and so there's no real workaround for having to set the scale explicitly in accordance with the driver's wishes (which the generic ADO.NET layer doesn't know about). You could consider writing a simple utility method to patch up any `OleDbParameterCollection` before a command is executed (and/or wrapper types to serve as factories). Depending on your app this may or may not be comfortable to do. Using strings of the form `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fff` is another possibility (not one I'd prefer, though).

Comment: You have correctly identified the issue as the "scale" - for compatibility it needs to be set to 3 for the Timestamp types. Note for SQL smalldatetime, the scale must be 0 and for SQL datetime it must be 3 to stop the truncation. The only other alternative has already been mentioned - convert to a string and then SQL does the conversion without issue.